# Windows 8 store app: How dynamically change Binding in ListViewItem

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have created a common control for listView and I want to change the content of each item in the listView. Something like DisplayMemberPath but I need to send two values ​​that are not the same for any one screen.

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
       <Grid> 
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property1}"/>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Setter2}"/>
       </Grid>
     </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

and on the next screen I want something like this

```
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SuperNewProperty}"/>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Setter2xyz}"/>
```

How do I create a control which has variable binding like:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding {Binding MySpecificValue}"/>
```

This is obviously a stupid thing, but it best describes what I want to do.

**For completion:**

Ok i have some module Employes.xaml 
where call, my control with some dependency properties as itemSource and prop1, prop2(I want to use both, like display member path).

ItemSource is IEnumerable from DB and contains 2 columns: employeName, employNumber, this will be displayed on the listView

```
<control:listViewMyControl itemSource ="{Binding employes}" prop1="employeName" prop2="employNumber" />
```

but when i have modul Cities.xaml 
I need binding prop1, prop2 to another column name, cityName, cityRank or whatever

```
<control:listViewMyControl itemSource ="{Binding cities}" prop1="cityName" prop2="cityRank " />
```

The problem comes when I want to display two different types of listviewitems for listview

```
   // my user control listViewMyControl 
    <ListView x:Name="listView1">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <Grid> 
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding employeName}"/>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding employeNumber}"/>

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding cityName}"/>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding cityRank}"/>

   // but i want only something like display member path for two labels, input modules may be more (employes, cities, cars, stations, .....) something like this
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding {Binding MySpecificValue}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding {Binding MySpecificValue2}"/> 
           </Grid>
         </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there are probably many ways, a datatemplateselector, a change in the viewmodel, a converter... give a more specific example about your viewmodel and the "next screen"